# Configure unixODBC on AIX - Driver Manager can't open lib

Tags: odbc, aix, unixodbc

We installed unixODBC on Aix 7.1 to connect with Oracle. When we tried test the connection using isql, we received the following error:

```
isql -v ORACLE
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib  '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/client_1/lib/libsqora.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

After that, we run ldd command on libsqora.so to verify:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/client_1/lib/libsqora.so needs:
     /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.a(libodbcinst.so.1)
ar: 0707-109 Member name libodbcinst.so.1 does not exist.
dump: /tmp/tmpdir26149042/extract/libodbcinst.so.1: 0654-106 Cannot open the specified file.
     /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libdl.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libperfstat.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libodm.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libc.a(aio_64.o)
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libcfg.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/liblvm.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libcorcfg.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libsrc.a(shr_64.o)
```

As you see, libodbcinst.so.1 file is not find. We reviewed libodbcinst.a, using the command below, and instead of libodbcinst.so.1, libodbcinst.so.2 is inside libodbcinst.a.

```
ar -X32 -t libodbcinst.a
```

So, We tried to create a link using:

```
ln -s libodbcinst.so.1 libodbcinst.so.2
```

But still have the same error.

Any idea what is going on?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a 64-bit shared object called `libodbcinst.so.1` whithin `/usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.a`. I suggest you do this

```
mkdir -p /tmp/workplace
cd /tmp/workplace
cp -p /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.a /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.bak

ar -X64 x /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.a libodbcinst.so.2
mv libodbcinst.so.2 libodbcinst.so.1
ar -X64 rcs /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.a libodbcinst.so.1
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I realize the unixODBC was installed in 32-bits. I tried to compile again, using gcc, on 64-bits but an error appear. Before I execute the configure command, I run export CFLAGS, ARFLAGS and OBJECT_MODE. The configure command run successfully, but when I run "make" command, the following error appears: ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .lt_dlinit. Any idea?

Comment: library `libltdl` comes from libtool. http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Libtool